# Rails view: display text and a link, conditionally ; Is there a simpler way than this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

In a Rails (erb) view, I want to conditionaly display some text and a link.

Is there anything simpler than that:

```
<% if some_condition %>
        Go to  
<%=     link_to("Home", root_url) %>
<%  else %>
        See all
<%=     link_to("objects", my_objects_path) %>
<%  end %>
```

I am a bit annoyed by the number of `<%` and `<%=` tags.

Comment: Switch to HAML ;) http://haml-lang.com

Comment: Yes; put it in a partial or a helper.

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a helper (depending on actual usage, it could be an application-wide helper, a model helper, etc):

```
def home_or_objects c
  if c
    link_to "Go to home", root_url
  else
    link_to "See all objects", my_objects_path
  end
end
```

*(I wouldn't linkinate only a single word--smaller target, and IMO less communicative. YMMV.)*

Then in the view:

```
<%= home_or_objects some_condition %>
```

As a partial it's a matter of rendering the partial, perhaps passing the condition in as a local, or if it's an instance variable, it can be referenced directly without needing to be passed.

```
<%= render :partial => 'home_or_objects', :locals => { :c => some_condition } %>
```

(There are a few ways a partial could be handled. IMO a helper is more appropriate.)